# Linked list implementation segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have done basic implementation of Linked List but its giving Segmentation fault on uncommenting the commented lines otherwise its working fine.
I am not able to understand why its giving the error. 
Please give me some help

```
void insert(Node **head, Symbol sym) {
    Node *temp, *p = *head;;
    Symbol a = sym;
    temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->value = a;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (p == NULL)
        *head = temp;
    else {
        while (p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        p->next = temp;
    }
}

void printList(Node *head) {
    Node *p = head;
    if(p == NULL) return;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main() {
    Node *List, *list2;
    insert(&List, 0);
    insert(&List, 1);

    //insert(&list2, 2);
    //insert(&list2, 3);

    printList(List);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger like `gdb` and step through.

Comment: `Node *List=NULL, *list2=NULL;`

Comment: Apart from personal development or an application where the additional bytes per node and processing steps per function needs to be kept low. Should people not be using GList from the GObject library or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not initialize initial pointers to nodes

```
Node *List, *list2;
```

Write

```
Node *List = NULL, *list2 = NULL;
```

Take into account that variable `list2` is not used in the program you showed.

The other way to write function `insert` is the following

```
void insert( Node **head, Symbol sym ) 
{
    Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->value = sym;
        temp->next  = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;
        *head = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie  Does it mean that I may not give my own answer?:)

Comment: It would have been nice if you referenced Bluepix to give him the credit of the solution.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie  Oh, I am sorry. When I was writing my post I had not seen yet the comments.:)